# Creation of timestamps in milliseconds for df in r

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, interpolation, milliseconds

I have sensor data and want to create missing timestamps and interpolate the values for features. At the moment I have measurements with varying duration between them. And I would like to have a higher amount. A simplified df below

```
df1 = data.frame (
    value =c('5','15','10','10','5','15'),
    time = as.POSIXct(c('2018-06-03 19:40:00','2018-06-03 19:42:00','2018-06-03 19:43:00','2018-06-03 19:45:00','2018-06-03 19:46:00','2018-06-03 19:48:00')))
```

If I am doing it like this using padr package, it works.

```
df2=df1 %>% pad(start_val = df1$time[1], end_val = df1$time[6],interval = "sec")
df2$value <- na.approx(df2$value)
```

But I would like to create timestamps each 0.1 or 0.2 seconds. The padr package can handle 2 seconds, but it seems that less than 1 second not works as I am getting this message

> ```
> Error: The specified interval is invalid for the datetime variable.
> Not all original observation are in the padding.
> If you want to pad at this interval, aggregate the data first with thicken.
> ```

Is there a possibility to create timestamps in a smaller interval than 1 second?
I tried this

```
seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(df1$time[1]), as.POSIXct(df1$time[6]), units = "seconds", by = .2)
```

But it creates only a vector of timestamps

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to employ .1 or .2, and keep the date structure and interpolate values, this works (note that you can change the .1 or .2 in the seq call).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(padr)
library(zoo)

df1 = data.frame (
  value =c('5','15','10','10','5','15'),
  time = as.POSIXct(c('2018-06-03 19:40:00','2018-06-03 19:42:00',
                      '2018-06-03 19:43:00','2018-06-03 19:45:00',
                      '2018-06-03 19:46:00','2018-06-03 19:48:00')))

# format decimal seconds so that it can be used to compare to the new date range
df1$time <- format(df1$time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS2")

# create the interval
y = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(df1$time[1]), as.POSIXct(df1$time[6]), units = "seconds", by = .2)

# set up new data frame for original values and interpolation
dy = data.frame(time = y,
                value = NA) %>% 
  mutate(time = format(y, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS2"))

# obtain row numbers of those that already have values
wh <- sapply(df1$time, function(x) which(dy$time == x))

# return the original values to the dataset
dy[wh, ]$value <- unlist(df1$value)

# interpolate
dy$value <- na.approx(dy$value)

# take a look
head(dy)
#                     time    value
# 1 2018-06-03 19:40:00.00 5.000000
# 2 2018-06-03 19:40:00.20 5.016667
# 3 2018-06-03 19:40:00.40 5.033333
# 4 2018-06-03 19:40:00.59 5.050000
# 5 2018-06-03 19:40:00.79 5.066667
# 6 2018-06-03 19:40:01.00 5.083333
```

Comment: I am getting this error message: > # return the original values to the dataset
> dy[wh, ]$value <- unlist(df1$value)
Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: What is the class of the object `wh` in your environment? If it is anything other than `integer` then change the code to `dy[unlist(wh), ] <- unlist(df1$value)`. (In hindsight, I should have used `vapply`, not `sapply`.)

Comment: `wh` is `integer` class

Comment: I'm a little stumped! What is in the object `wh`?  Is `dy` a data frame with a column named `value`?  If you run `unlist(df1$value)` in the console, what is the output?

Comment: `dy` is a dataframe with time column and value column with `NA`. `wh` is list of length 6 with time and integer (0). `unlist(df1$value) [1] "5"  "15" "10" "10" "5"  "15" `

Comment: It's working now. I started R again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `padr`, but that last call should give you a sequence with sub-second differences, it might just not be printed as such. The section **Sub-second Accuracy** in `?DateTimeClasses` explains:

> Classes "POSIXct" and "POSIXlt" are able to express fractions of a
> second. (Conversion of fractions between the two forms may not be
> exact, but will have better than microsecond accuracy.)
>
> Fractional seconds are printed only if options("digits.secs") is set:
> see strftime.

Thus,

```
options("digits.secs"=TRUE)

st <- Sys.time()
st.s <- seq(st, st+1, 0.1)
diff(st.s)
# Time differences in secs
#  [1] 0.099999905 0.100000143 0.099999905 0.100000143 0.099999905 0.099999905
#  [7] 0.100000143 0.099999905 0.100000143 0.099999905

st
# [1] "2021-12-29 20:00:33.0 CET"
dput(st)
# structure(1640804433.02173, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))

options("digits.secs"=FALSE)

st
# [1] "2021-12-29 20:00:33 CET"
dput(st)
# structure(1640804433.02173, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
```

Same data, just printed with more accuracy.